# vein feature extraction using pixel by pixel in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working in dorsal hand vein recognition system. I have already obtained a thinned version of the veins and now i have to proceed for the `feature extraction` as shown below.

http://imageshack.us/a/img194/5490/0059hv1.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img543/9764/zsthin0059hv1.png

As seen from the above pic, the first is the original image. Image normalisation followed by histogram equalistion, adaptive thresholding, wiener filter and thinning algorithm give the second image.

From there, I need to process the image for feature extraction to be used for matching.

I will be grateful if someone can provide me with the code to loop through all the pixels in the thinned vein pattern (image 2) using matlab and store each pixel value in a notepad file which will be used for matching purpose.

Thank You

Comment: I cannot infer anything about the problem you are facing, what you have tried, what is the desired output etc. You should upload your image somewhere, then tell us in short what you did to get that image? Then tell us what you want (maybe by making another image) or in words. Then we can give you suggestion. For example, I don't know why you used `find` function

Comment: OK. Is there a specific website for uploading images or its fine if uploaded here itself?

Comment: You can post your image on imageshack[dot]us

Comment: Hello, images already posted. Refer to http://imageshack.us/a/img194/5490/0059hv1.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img543/9764/zsthin0059hv1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [bwboundaries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html). It can give you exactly what you want.

Use it as:

```
B = bwboundaries(BW);
```

B will contain 5 cells (according to my estimate after having a look at the image). Each cell will contain `nx2` vector which contains `x` and `y` coordinates of the curve. After getting the coordinates, you can get the pixel values from the original location as follows. Suppose `[row,col]` contains the `x` and `y` coordinates of a curve, you can get the pixel values using `sub2ind`. Then use `textwrite` to write the values in notepad file.

I will leave some things for you to figure out.

Comment: but bwboundaries will trace the vein pixels twice.

Comment: so use unique function to filter them out. Actually use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15242-myunique) function. Since MATLAB's unique function sorts the elements which you don't want.

Comment: Hi, I have already obtained the (x, y) coordinates of the veins as per your instruction. However, when applying sub2ind to get the pixel values, I get it only in terms of 1 and 0. I presume this is because the second image is in binary form. So how can I proceed to obtain the correct pixel value. Thank You.

Comment: suppose you obtained the binary image from the original image, say `img`. Then in `[row,col]` you have the coordinates of veins. Then use `pixelValue=img(sub2ind(size(img),row,col);`. You should get a vector of pixel values in `pixelValue`. Hope its clear now.

Comment: So if I have well understood, lets assume <!--img_vein--> to be the image containing the thinned vein patterns and from which we have extracted the vein coordinates and <!--img--> represents only the binaryimage.  For the pixelvalue formula, is it correct for the row to be followed by col? Thank You

Comment: `img_vein` and `img` are both binary images according to your description. That won't give you actual pixel values. For them, you have to use the grayscale image. So you want those pixel values which are given by `[row,col]`. If you use the command given by me in the previous comment, you will get the output (provided `img` is the original image).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. Finally i got it. One last thing to clear before I mark the answer as accepted. Is it correct to have similar pixel values? For instance, at vein coordinates of (62, 136); (62, 137); (62, 138); and (76, 175), the pixel value is 32. Thank You.

Comment: You can only confirm it. Just show the original image using `imshow` and then check if the above location have the same value. You can also check 15-20 random locations to see if your implementation is correct. Also, conceptually it is correct to have similar pixel values at many places in the image.